# How to use LIKE condition in SQL with parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the filter in a view like this  `SELECT ID FROM X WHERE (ID LIKE '17%')` it works

but I couldn't to use with a parameter that I get the value of a textbox

```
SELECT ID FROM X WHERE (ID LIKE @Param1)
```

Thanks for your help.

I used a lot of combinations but no results.

Comment: Have you added a `%`?

Comment: If your ID column is an `int` it's gonna perform badly because it has to convert every single one to a string first.

Comment: Agreed, if you want to compare ints then use a range eg `ID >= 170 AND ID < 180`

Comment: yes i added % but i have error or not result

Comment: it works provided you convert the number into nvarchar and put the value in @Param1 with %
BR

Comment: You need to show exactly what you tried and show the exact error message you received. We can't read your mind.